# Source Not Found: Adding the source attachment to view source code

Tags: java, eclipse

I am unable to view the JavaCore.class source code, although I am able to use the code just fine.

For example, to view the source code of the method `JavaCore.create(..)`, I `ctrl - click` (or press `f3`) on the `create` in `JavaCore.create(ResourceUtility.getWorkspaceRoot());`. But instead of an editor with the source code, I get the following message:

```
**Class File Editor**

**Source Not Found**

The source attachment does not contain the source for the file JavaCore.class.

You can change the source attachment by clicking Change Attached Source below:
```

I listed the contents of the default source attachment, `~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.0_758590624_linux_gtk_x86_64/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.9.0.201212161923.jar`, as follows:

```
`jar tvf ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.3.0_758590624_linux_gtk_x86_64/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.9.0.201212161923.jar `
```

When I searched "JavaCore" in the output, I found only the following files:

```
   618 Sun Dec 16 19:23:18 PST 2012 org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaCore$1.class
  1746 Sun Dec 16 19:23:18 PST 2012 org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaCore$2.class
 66406 Sun Dec 16 19:23:18 PST 2012 org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaCore.class
  1758 Sun Dec 16 19:23:18 PST 2012 org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaCore.java.rej
```

Does this mean I do not have the source under this jar? If not, where would the source code be?

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) and I have Eclipse installed under `~/eclipse/` (which contains my `plugins/`, `dropins/`, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you need to obtain the JDT source from the SDK. If your version of Eclipse is 4.3.0 then you can grab the JDT SDK from here: http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3-201306052000/download.php?dropFile=org.eclipse.jdt.source-4.3.zip .

I found this on this archive page for Eclipse 4.3.0: http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.3-201306052000/

EDIT: After downloading the zip, the file you want is `plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core.source_3.9.0.v20130604-1421.jar` (although the date stamp on the file is different to your binary...)

Comment: Thanks! But I already had the  file under my `~/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core.source_3.9.0.v20130604-1421.jar` directory. Do you know why Eclipse did not find the file location on its own? (re my answer below)

Comment: Ah, I should have checked there first :)  Not sure - did you explicitly load the jar as a library in your project by referencing the external jar under the plugins dir? If so, then you would need to attach the source as you normally would for libraries like that.

Comment: To my knowledge, no I didn't. Although I wonder why I have two eclipse installations - one under `~/eclipse` and another under `~/.eclipse`. I am launching from `~/eclipse/eclipse`, so it does not make sense that my files are referencing the `~/.eclipse/plugins` directory. I wonder what is the purpose of my `~/.eclipse` directory? Should I delete it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the source code under `~/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core.source_3.9.1.v20130905-0837.jar` for this example. I am not sure why Eclipse was defaulting to the `~/.eclipse/` directory for the source code when there are many source code ".jars" under `~/eclipse/plugins/`.